# Using SQL in Query that auto updates

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Thank you beforehand for your assistance. I know enough about Access, SQL, and VBA to get myself into trouble. Here is what I want to do.

I want to create a query that starts with a certain year and then lists each year up until the current year. The problem is that I want the query to automatically update as time progresses. In other words, say the start year is 2009, I want my query to list 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, and 2013 since we are currently in the year 2013. Next year, the list will expand to include 2014. I suspect this is possible using a query in SQL but not sure how to go about coding it properly.

Comment: With the example do you want to output a single row with five columns, or five rows with a single column each?

Comment: Single column with five rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to create a Query Criteria that does what I need.

Like (Right(Year(Now()),2)-3) & "-*" Or Like (Right(Year(Now()),2)-2) & "-*" Or Like (Right(Year(Now()),2)-1) & "-*" Or Like Right(Year(Now()),2) & "-*"

Thank you everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that there is no simple solution for this simple process. We must use VBA to perform following steps:

#### Create a temporary table:

```
CREATE Table tblTmpYears (
  ID COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY,
  Year Long
);
```

In VBA:

```
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "CREATE Table tblTmpYears (" _
  & " ID COUNTER CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY," _
  & " Year Long" _
  & ");"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

#### Fill the temporary table:

```
INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (year) VALUES (2009);
INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (year) VALUES (2010);
INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (year) VALUES (2011);
INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (year) VALUES (2012);
INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (year) VALUES (2013);
```

In VBA, for 5 years, valid even after 100 years after our life existence:

```
Dim y as long, ymin, ymax, strSQL 
ymax = Year(Date)
ymin = ymax - 4
For y = ymin to ymax
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblTmpYears (Year) VALUES (" & y & ");"
  CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
Next
```

#### Create a query for listing with the temporary table:

```
SELECT * FROM tblStudents INNER JOIN tblTmpYears
  ON tblStudents.Year=tblTmpYears.Year
  ORDER BY Year;
```

In VBA like this:

```
Dim qdf, strSQL
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblStudents INNER JOIN tblTmpYears" _
  & " ON tblStudents.Year=tblTmpYears.Year" _
  & " ORDER BY Year;"
Set qdf = CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef("qrySelTemporary", strSQL)
DoCmd.OpenQuery qdf.Name
```

Here you will have the Query Datasheet Windows with your students's list, it's printable. Even better, you can use it as

```
MyReport.RecordSource = "qrySelTemporary"
```

in an Access Report with a beautiful presentation.

#### Delete the temporary table after printing, for example:

```
DROP TABLE tblTmpYears;
```

In VBA:

```
Dim strSQL
strSQL = "DROP TABLE tblTmpYears;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Only VBA can accomplish this... rather than a single SQL query.

Comment: What about using a While..Wend statement? While YrValue < year(now()) YrValue = YrValue + 1. I'm just having problems exporting it into a column for display each time. Also, your VBA doesn't automatically update based on the year of the current date. That is what is needed the most.

Comment: Yes absolutely, a year loop must be used to insert the year values.

Comment: `TempVars.Add "yrTemp", 2010

While yrTemp < year(now())

    yrTemp = yrTemp + 1

Wend`
My issue is just putting the results into a 1 column temp table in SQL. I'm using this to limit another query based on user choice of which year is selected.

Answer (score 0):

How about this - a small VBA function that outputs the SQL for an appropriate UNION query, which you can then assign as the RowSource for a combo box, use as a sub-query inside another dynamically generated query, or whatever:

```
Function CreateYearsToCurrentSQL(From As Integer) As String
  Dim I As Integer, S As String
  For I = From To Year(Date)
    If I <> From Then S = S + "UNION "
    S = S + "SELECT " & I & " AS Year FROM MSysObjects" + vbNewLine
  Next I
  CreateYearsToCurrentSQL = S
End Function
```

The `FROM MSysObjects` is because Access will whinge about no `FROM` clause if one isn't there, and `MSysObjects` is bound to be an existing table in an Access context (if you prefer though, replace it with the name of any other table).

Comment: I assume I would put this function as a button click or some other event in a form. I'm not sure where to go from there though.

Comment: @Dragonsen - no, it's a standalone function that creates the SQL for a SELECT query. If you don't want to populate a combo or list box, and you don't want to create a DAO Recordset object, what exactly do you want?